# How to make StatefulWidget with global key in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile

I'm new to Flutter, and I think I might just have things set up weird. Most of what's setup so far is from small tutorials. I currently have my main.dart rendering just a userCheck Widget, which will eventually be used to connect with backend and check whether or not I have a valid user token.

```
class UserCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserCheck({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  UserCheckState createState() => UserCheckState();
}

class UserCheckState extends State<UserCheck> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var userExists = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return userExists
        ? Home()
        : new LoginForm();
  }
}
```

The Home Widget would eventually load information from the backend, given there's a proper user. Right now, userExists obviously defaults to false. This loads the LoginForm just fine. My current goal is when a user logs in, to assume that it's a good login, then reversing userExists to be true, thus opening the Home page. This is the LoginForm setup:

````
  LoginForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  UserCheckState parent;

  @override
  LoginFormState createState() => LoginFormState();
}

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var userData = {};
  bool login = true;
  String loginText = 'Sign Up';

  void updateField(String value, String field) {
    setState(() {
      userData = {
        ...userData,
        '$field': value,
      };
    });
  }

  void sendHome() {
    setState(() {
      // this.parent.parent.userExists = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        login
            ? Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter a username', labelText: 'Username'),
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a username';
                        }
                        updateField(value, 'username');
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter your password',
                          labelText: 'Password'),
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a password';
                        }
                        updateField(value, 'password');
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('hit here');
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            print('hit here two');
                            sendHome();
                            print(userData);
                            // if API responds with proper token

                            // API call to login
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : SignupForm(),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              login = !login;
              loginText = loginText == 'Sign Up' ? 'Log In' : 'Sign Up';
            });
          },
          child: Text(loginText),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}```

I don't know if there's some sort of router that would be better and is already implemented as switching Widgets, but I haven't found anything from my own searches.
````

Comment: For better code maintainability and efficiency I will strongly recommend you use a state management system that does that for you. Check [this](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial) it will make your life way easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to get back to the `userCheck` widget if the user logs in. Instead, you can go to the `Home` screen directly by using `Navigator` to make a transition from the `Login` page to the `Home` page. Put the navigator right after the line the user gets a valid token inside the `onPressed` function of your `Submit` button:

```js
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // Goes to Home screen.
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Home(),
      ));
    }
  },
  child: Text('Submit'),
),
```